# develop shared library alongside another project without having them be in the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, class-library

Let's say I have a c# project Foo and a classlibrary called Bar

I'm wanting to develop Bar alongside Foo which will use Bar as a shared library. I'd like to keep these Foo and Bar in their own git repositories.

When I debug Foo, I'd like to be able to step into Bar to see what it's doing under the hood. When I make changes to Bar, I'd like to be able to have my changes reflected in Foo. It's okay if I'd have to build Bar first for my changes to take effect.

When I eventually deploy Foo, I'd like to import Bar as a nuget package, rather than including it as a part of the solution for Foo

Is this possible in c#? I've been trying to develop a shared library and a repository that uses that library as a template for future projects. I've tried to publish Bar as a nuget package to my local filesystem but it's been giving me problems; I'm unable to step into functions that call into Bar from project Foo and when I make changes to Bar I have to build, pack, then publish the library again. If I don't bump the version number of bar when I do this, this results in errors where I have to go to the nuget package in my filesystem and delete it manually.

### Aside

If you're interested Bar contains extension methods for setting up a connection to a message broker along with classes for configuration definition and "contract" classes that need to be shared among projects.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer and change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wanting to develop Bar alongside Foo which will use Bar as a shared library. I'd like to keep these Foo and Bar in their own git repositories.

Yes. In Foo, add all files from Bar as needed by `add as Link`. Namespaces and files will be honored as if they existed in Foo; but no files will be copied...only referenced.

---

This is an old Silverlight trick to share one set of code *between two projects* because of the two different versions of the CLR from the web services to the Silverlight project. It allowed models to be brought over from the web services without trying to pull in a dll which had a totally different CLR.

---

Create the code in project 1. Then for project 2, add the files by *linking* them from project 1. To do that type of add, its really adding a symbolic *link* to the file(s).

#### How

The trick is to include as a link into the project as needed.

1. In the second project right click and select `Add` then `Existing Item...` or <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Browse to the location of the file(s) found in the first project and select the file(s).
3. Once the file(s) have been selected, then on the `Add` button select the drop down arrow.
4. Select `Add as link` to add the *common* files(s) as a link into the project.

[image]

---

> I'm unable to step into functions that call into Bar from project Foo and when I make changes to Bar I have to build, pack, then publish the library again.

The linking of files, as mentioned, will gain access to the file *as if* the file was actually within the project, but the file physically resides elsewhere. If the linked file(s) change, those changes are reflected in the project that linked them in. Building due to changes still applies, but that should be minor.

Comment: If you want the linked files to show up in their own "Bar" folder you can add the `LinkBase` property in the `Foo.csproj`: `<Compile Include="../../Bar/**/*.cs" LinkBase="Bar" />`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when developing code in nuget dependency chains.
One solution is to use something like [NuGetReferenceSwitcher](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NuGetReferenceSwitcher).
The disadvantage is that the tool will change your csproj files back and forth and you need to take good care of not commiting unwanted changes.

Another solution I employ successfully is to create a sibling project to your Foo project that uses `ProjectReference` to Bar instead of `PackageReference`.
I detailed the approach on [my blog](https://svenhuebner-it.com/advanced-msbuild-adding-a-projectreference-sibling-project-to-a-packagereference-project/).
It involves editing your project files by hand, which is simple in SDK-style projects.
If you are comfortable with (or want to learn) that, here is the Gist:

1. Extract everything except the `PackageReference` to Bar from the Foo project into a `Foo.props` file.
2. Import that `Foo.props` file into the Foo project. Note that until now, effectively nothing has changed.
3. Create a copy of the `Foo.csproj` in some other folder and name it e. g. `FooDev.csproj`. Link the source files from the Foo (sic!) project into the FooDev project (using the technique that ΩmegaMan already described in their answer). Include `FooDev.csproj` in your Foo solution.
4. In your `FooDev.cproj` change the `PackageReference` to Bar to a `ProjectReference`.

You now have both a `Foo.csproj` that uses a `PackageReference` to Bar and a `FooDev.csproj` that uses a `ProjectReference` to Bar.
You will be able to immediately see the effects of the changes you make to Bar on the FooDev project.

Answer (score 0):

you can go red path or blue.

*"Is this possible in c#?"* - This is not c# or any language. This is solution/project management. Many things are possible. You can definitely develop as raw projects or DLL. Include debug-built DLL and PDB file into your nuget, and you will be able to step through your referenced library.

You don't have to use a separate solution from yout GIT/TFS. You can develop using any local solution, not binded to source control.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't try this out right now, but I believe this is what we used to do (several jobs ago).

1. Create a project/solution for Bar, deploying it to a local NuGet package source. Add it to its own Git repo.
2. Create a project/solution for Foo, dependent on Bar via Nuget. Put it in a separate repo.
3. Create a FooPlusBar solution *in the same folder (and repo) as Foo.sln*. Start with an empty solution. Then add the Foo project and them the Bar project. If you are careful to keep changes to Bar updated in the NuGet package, I'm pretty sure you can get the debugger to recognize the Bar sources when you are debugging Foo from within the FooPlusBar solution. Yes, a single project can be part of more than one solution

Again, I *think* should mostly just work (no guarantees, though). I don't remember if you need to update the version number of the Bar package every time you make a change